# How do I list all the hadoop jobs run by a particular user?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to find a command that I can use to list all the jobs that I am currently running. 
"hadoop job -list" lists all the jobs. Is there a way to filter the list by user?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply grep the output using username

```
hadoop job -list | grep <username>
```

Comment: Or even hadoop job -list | grep `whoami`

Comment: you mean hadoop job -list | grep \`whoami\` ?